# check string for nothing and then for certain value in 1 line?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, string

I always seem to see if a string (querystring value usually) has a value but first I have to check that it is not nothing first so I end up with 2 if then statements - am I missing somethign here  - there has to be a better way to do this:

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) Then
  If CBool(myString) Then
   //code
   End If
End If
```

Comment: The problem with that is I get an Invalid Cast Exception because myString is nothing when the Cbool is applied, here is the error: > Conversion from string "" to type
> 'Boolean' is not valid.

Comment: Just a recommendation, you should use the Boolean.TryParse to check for valid string/boolean conversions, then use Boolean.Parse to actually parse them out.

For getting used to .Net, it is best to start using the .Net methods instead of the Visual Basic legacy "helpers".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In VB.Net, And does not short-circuit, but [AndAlso](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cb8x3kfz(VS.80).aspx) does.

(same for Or and OrElse)

So your code should look something like

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(myString) AndAlso CBool(myString) Then 
    ....
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

The boolean "and" operator in your language of choice? Conditionals generally short-circuit so if the first one fails, the second won't run/error.

Comment: you want to check that vb.net short-circuits... vbscript didn't. (Huge annoyance)

Answer (score 1):

AndAlso (as mentioned) is the most general purpose answer. But, you could also use the various TryParse methods, which will make code like this:

```
Dim b as Boolean
If Boolean.TryParse(myString, b) AndAlso b Then
End If
```

Bonus, it'll save you from the FormatException when someone sends in "blah" in your querystring.

Comment: downvote because the "AndAlso b" is evaluating if b is true. it should simply read:  

Dim b as Boolean If Boolean.TryParse(myString, b) Then End If

Comment: @Russ - nope, the AndAlso b is (mostly) equivalent to the original If CBool(myString) line. In this scenario, you need both.

Comment: did you run the code? because i did and what i am saying is true.  you dont need "AndAlso b"

Comment: If myString is "False", then you need AndAlso b, otherwise you'd run the inner block - when the original code would not.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this type of code fits perfect as an "extension method". In short this means that you can extend string with a method providing your own code.

Look it up :)

Comment: But you can't extend a type with static methods (though I think F# allows this). So you can't have String.IsNotNullOrEmptyOrFalse() - but you could have "abcd".IsNotNullOrEmptyOrFalse(). But that's just confusing if you call it a null object.

Comment: Yes you can - I have written a number of extension methods of the type: String.IsEmail(), String.IsDecimal(), String.IsDate, etc - that's the whole point of Extension Methods: "Extension methods enable you to "add" methods to existing types without creating a new derived type"

Comment: @Zhaph - the extensions are off an *instance* of the type. Meaning, you'd call it like "abcd".IsEmail(). You can't do an extension like String.IsEmail("abcd"). So, if you have a null string, your code would effectively read null.IsNotNullOrEmptyOrFalse. Which is just weird (though legal).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following if using .NET 2.0 or greater:

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(thestringobject)
```

Will evaluate to True or False depending.
I usually create another function in a Utility Class that does this check and also checks the trim/length so I know if the string object is null, empty, or a bunch of blanks.